# Powerapp filter by user's office location

Tags: filter, powerapps, office365connectors

I can't get this to work!!!

I have a visitor registration powerapp, my data source is sharepoint list.The selectoffice column is a people column and the show filed is office.

[sp column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JB4oe.png)

I have a gallery for the administrators to mass checkout visitors for their office.

If I'm logging and my office is Toronto, I want to see the visitors in the Toronto Office.

O35.Officelocation="selectOffice".LOCATION
But location is not available for selection. only display name, claims,email, image, department.
Can some one help me ?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that Filter works on complex types (e.g., person) but sort does not.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZZTp.png)

Comment: Please add the answer as text, images are not readable by screen-readers and can get removed over time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that Sharepoint Person-type columns have Office Location attributes. Use the Office365Users Connection instead. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/connections/connection-office365-users